# What is the easiest cipher to use in designing double ciphers?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, multiple-encryption

I want to make a double cipher consisting of two encryption method Enc1 and Enc2, and two corresponding decryption mechanisms Dec1 and Dec2. I want it so that:

(1) we can encrypt any message M1 to a ciphertext C1 using Enc1  and a key K1, and it can decrypt the ciphertext C1 with Dec1, using the same key to recover M1.

(2) There exist key K2, where Dec2(C1,K2) = M2 and Enc2(M2,K2) = C1, and M2 makes sense(intelligible).

In conclusion, I want to make a cipher designed for a scenario in which if someone were forced to decrypt the ciphertext, they could do so with a different key K2 to produce a message that makes sense but is not the original message.

What is the best cipher to use to accomplish this?

Comment: @kelalaka I think this is less about double encryption and related security gains, but rather about wanting a different security / correctness property than regular encryption. An example implementation of this would be TrueCrypt / VeraCrypt's hidden disk feature.

Comment: Also note that if an adversary knows about the ability to embed a second message, and they forced the fake password out of you, they might just continue and try to force a second key out of you, even if there's none (as they never "loose" anything when trying to force a second key out of you).

Comment: @SEJPM you are right, however [Not easy to achieve the [Plausible deniability](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/81020/18298)

Comment: how about a simple one-time pad?

Comment: @user253751 how do you keep the key?